# $x \neq x$ in a consistent system

Tags: logic

I believe that it is refutable that $x \neq x$ in $T$, where $T$ is a consistent extension of $Q$. What is a simple proof of this (or, if I am wrong, why is this not the case)?

Comment: Surely that will depend on the theory.  Not all theories will even contain a symbol "$\ne $" or have a way of expressing it.

Comment: Sorry, edited it in: $T$ a consistent extension of $Q$.

Comment: $x=x$ is an axiom of first order logic with equality.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Robinson's arithmetic, aka $Q$, is undecidable. Furthermore, it proves:
$$
Q \vdash \forall x: x = x
$$
and thus as a corollary
$$
Q \vdash x = x
$$
for the free variable x. Remember that you cannot prove the consistency of $Q$ from within $Q$, so you cannot hope for something along the lines of
$$
Q \vdash \not \exists x: x \not = x
$$
or rewritten as
$$
\vdash Q  \rightarrow \not \exists x: x \not = x
$$
If it could prove that it doesn't prove this, it would prove it's own consistency - and therefore be inconsistent. This holds for all extensions of $Q$ as well. Of course, you can do something like the following:
$$ PA \vdash (Q \rightarrow \not \exists x: x \not = x) $$
but I guess that's not the point. Otherwise, sure. Take any consistent and stronger theory $T$ proving the consistency of $Q$. Then it will prove that there is no element for which $Q$ thinks this element is unequal to itself, since if there were such an element, $Q$ would be inconsistent.

Comment: But saying that formula $P$ is *refutable*, means that $\lnot P$ is *provable*. Thus $\lnot (x=x)$ is refutable iff $(x=x)$ is provable (assuming classical logic, where double negation holds). And $\forall x (x=x)$ is an axiom of FOL with equality, that means that $\mathsf Q \vdash (x=x)$, i.e. $\mathsf Q \vdash \lnot \lnot (x=x)$. Conclusion :  $\lnot (x=x)$ **is** refutable in $\mathsf Q$.

Comment: In every FOL theory we have $\vdash \lnot \exists x \lnot (x=x)$.

Comment: What you say following the words "Remember that" is wrong. Of course $Q$ can prove $\not\exists x \cdot x\neq x$ since that is logically equivalent to $\forall x \cdot x = x$. That doesn't show that $Q$ proves its own consistency, which is a statement involving the provability predicate encoded in the language of $Q$.